# Why do lots of professional football players shoot with this awkward, tricky and "unstable" technique?

Tags: football, technique

I've seen many shots like [this](https://youtu.be/-NSvbGxzpKk?t=143) one in real "high quality" football games. I'm wondering what benefits this shot does have in comparison with a "normal" shot like [that](https://youtu.be/cX-sIxavUjA?t=70).

I doubt the reason is of the shot angle or the precision.  Furthermore, I consider this shot as "less safe" against fails, because of the unstable foot positioning. ([fail example](https://youtu.be/e64P98YFnAs?t=687))
Initially I was thinking the shooting foot remains the same, but i was wrong - but still I'm wondering if that's really the argument for that kind of shooting?

**EDIT** I don't know if that technique has a particular "name", e.g. like the "elastico" trick, therefore I don't know a better title for my question.

Comment: The video in your first link seems to be [a pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_(association_football)) rather than a [shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_(association_football)).

Comment: In addition to the above, the kind of shot is known as a "rabona".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to make it difficult for the opponent to regain possession by confusing them. A normal shot makes the trajectory of the ball easily predictable, increasing the chances of losing possession. If the opponent doesn't know which way the player will kick the ball, it is hard for them to react to it quickly.

You are correct in saying that this shot is "unstable" as compared to the conventional shots. However, players do not play these shots on a whim, they practice these thoroughly before executing them in the real game. With thorough practice, they can make the shot less "unstable". Obviously, that does not mean they can never fail, but with sufficient practice, they reduce the chances of that happening.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all: because they can
2. It might also just be the case of them not having enough trust in their weaker foot, and they just prefer to use their strongest foot.
3. Show off and entertain.